# How to access store in the mounted() method with NUXT.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, store, nuxt.js

I am working on my `NUXT.js` project with Open Street Map and I want to access `store` in the `mounted()` method. I received error that store is not defined in the `mounted()` method namespace. How can I access it?

**@/assets/js/utils.js**

```js
const utils = {

//...

updateMap(context) {
    let _context = context;

    const checkMapObject = setInterval(() => {
      if (_context.$refs.map) {
        _context.map = _context.$refs.map.mapObject;
        clearInterval(checkMapObject);

        //console.log(_context.map);

        if (process.browser) {
          L = require('leaflet');
          console.log("MAP OBJECT INITED");

          delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

          L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
            iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
            iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
            shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
          });

          for (let marker of this.getMapMarkers(_context.store.state.pollingStations)) {
            L.marker(marker).addTo(_context.map)
          }
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  },

// ...

}

export default utils;
```

**index.vue**

```html
<template>
   ...
</template>

<script>

...

import utils from '@/assets/js/utils'

export default {
  // ...

  mounted() {
    utils.updateMap(this)
  },

  // ...
}
</script>
```

And I have received this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why don't you create a method and call it from your mounted? It works for me, and it is a good practice.

Comment: @thanksd I have provided my sources.

Comment: If you've set up Vuex correctly, it would need to be `_context.$store` not `_context.store`.

Comment: @thanksd Thanks you very much! Stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you shall be able to read from its Vue component instance in mounted(). such as

```
mounted() {
  this.$store;
}
```

2. But the problem is this.$store is not guaranteed to be available at the time of `mounted()` being called.

While i am still figuring it out, I debug and notice that `this.$store` is not immediately available but will be available after certain time of `mounted`.

[image]
[image]

As of today, there is no official documentation that I could found describing at what point Vuex will be ready in the lifecycle. But I think `fetch` and its state  looks promising. I will try and report back.

Comment: As of today, probably due to https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7096, I keep getting error of `Cannot read property 'nbFetching' of undefined` when using fetching

Answer (score 0):

As $store is not enable immediately and you can't determine it, you can test it and us it only when available using this :

```js
mounted() {
    while (!this.$store) {
      // Do nothing
    }
    this.$store.commit('xxxx/xxx');
},
```

1. The while loop will loops again and again untill this.$store is not resolved to `undefined` anymore.
2. As the while loop is not looping anymore, the `this.$store.commit('xxxx/xxx');` line will be executed !!

With the help of this little trick, I can use `this.$store` as soon as it is available, directly with the help of the mounted method.